# Time-efficient matrix elements grouping and summing

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I'm interested in finding the quickest way of grouping the elements of a large matrix in sub-groups of NxM elements and them summing them together.
To be completely clear, I'm actually not interested in the "regrouped" matrice, but only in the final results where the elements are summed.

## "Standard matrix" case

I'll show you an example below:

Say I have the following matrix 9x8:

```
test = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {8, 9}]
```

> [image]

I regroup it in sub-matrices NxM, in this example 3x2:

```
subtest = Partition[test, {2, 3}]
```

> [image]

and then I sum them together (as suggested in the comment by @:

```
out = MapAt[Total[#, -1] &, subtest, {All, All}];
```

> [image]

I could use other ways of summing the subgroups, as for example:

```
    out = Total /@ Flatten /@ # & /@ subtest;
```

Or using two nested tables, or for loops, etc.

My question is what is the fastest method for doing this? I need to do it on a 48k x 48k matrix, so I'd really need something reasonably quick.
Should I look into compiling nested for loops in C (not sure, I haven't ever tried)?

Something worth mentioning is that the entries of the matrix are all integers larger or equal to 0.

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments below, it's important to consider that most of the entries of the matrix (>99%) are zeroes. This might encourage a sparse array approach.

I'll add a (redundant) example with numeric values, thac can be however modified to larger matrices:

```
test = RandomInteger[1, {8, 9}];
```

> {{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
>     1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
>     0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}}

```
m = 3
n = 2
out = MapAt[Total[#, -1] &, Partition[test, {n, m}], {All, All}]
```

> {{3, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 3, 6}, {3, 4, 4}}

## Sparse array case

EDIT: In light of very useful discussion below, I'd like to add a "second question" (which is not really a different question).
How to do the same procedure described above, but when the input matrix is instead a sparse array?

Here a sample code for testing with a small sparse array:

```
test = SparseArray[{{5, 5} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {5, 3} -> 4}, {8, 9}];
```

and a sample code for testing with a nxn matrix where 99% of the entries are 0:

```
n = 100;
entries = {{#[[1]], #[[2]]} -> #[[3]]} & /@ RandomInteger[{1, n},{Ceiling[n*0.01], 3}];
SparseArray[Flatten@entries, {n, n}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: No need to map if you use the second argument of `Total[]`: `Total[Partition[test, {2, 3}], {3, 4}]`.

Comment: oh yes, you are absolutely right, I will change my post accordingly, thanks! Still, I'm not 100% sure this is the fastest solution

Comment: Converting entries to machine precision numbers will speed up the process. Integers in Mathematica are of arbitrary precision and often slows down the calculation.

Comment: @ukar True, but I think that converting a 48k x 48k matrix with N[] with take a lot of time, worth doing some testing though

Comment: @ukar: Wrong. When the integers do not exceed the bounda for machine integera (64 bit integers), _Mathematica_ has a chance to use packed arrays and machine integer computations. And indeed, the matrices generated by `RandomInteger[1, {n, n}]` are packed which can be checked with ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[test]``.

Comment: @Fraccalo Does the matrix have any structure that we may exploit? How is it created?

Comment: I fiddle with `ArrayResample[ ],` as in theory it is designed to do this sort of thing, but I couldn't get it to give the exactly what was wanted, and it what it gave took *much* longer to generate. Kind of surprising.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher the matrix is the result of a measurement (time of flight spectroscopy in a quantum optics lab). it indeed has a certain structure: most of the data are in "squares" of ~2k x 2k dimension, that are centred around the coordinates {24k,24k}, {24k,11.5k}, {24k,36.5k}, {11.5k,24k}, {36.5k,24k}. The rest are mostly 0, but there might be some 1 or 2 in random position due to background noise. I'm not sure this can help (but it would make sense to use sparse arrays as many entries of the matrix are actually zeros)

Comment: @Fraccalo Many zeroes are good. If there are enough of them, converting to `SparseArray` might speed up the pure `SparseArray`-method (example `c` below) tremendously. However, there is of course a cost for conversion... Actually, it would be much better if the input data could be acquired sparsely (in for form of nonzero positions) quite from the beginning.

Comment: Part1: I just checked and one of the data samples I have is a 48001x48001 matrix, and there are 2302707457 zeros, therefore 99.9% of the matrix entries are zeros. Therefore, it would be amazing to start with a sparse array. In principle, it might be possible to acquire the data sparsely, but it not something I can look into anytime soon: the data are acquired from a 400Gb highly compressed binary file, parsed and preprocessed in python and cython and exported as an .h5 file. I then open the file with MMA for doing some more processing with a library I wrote for my research.

Comment: Part2: the other problem, is that there are a bunch of function that I need to use on this dataset (as for example singular value decomposition) and I'm not sure it will be compatible with sparse arrays. But I guess one could think off working with sparse arrays and then convert to matrix when these functions are needed. The other problem will be to process the data as sparse array in python/cython (there must be a way) and make the export compatible with MMA. Anyway, I'll update the OP specifying the zeros property of the matrix.

Comment: The SVD of a sparse array is not guaranteed to be sparse, so you may need to be more clever than usual if your matrices are large enough to stress your machine's memory. As for file formats that can be handled by *Mathematica*, look up [Harwell-Boeing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HarwellBoeing.html) or [Matrix Market](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MTX.html).

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-lessthanks Thx!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Actually, I think I'll try to go for the sparse array solution (it feels wrong to use a massive matrix where I mostly have zeroes), I'll give a look at the python sparse array. I'll update the OP by considering a second case where my input matrix is a sparse array.

Comment: I thought this question might be a nice opportunity to try `BlockMap`, but after some superficial tests I have to conclude that it really isn't very fast...

Comment: Yeah, @SjoerdSmit, it is convenient at best.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less the .mtx does exactly what I needed, thx! Sparse arrays can be exported from python as .mtx and imported with MMA with basically zero effort!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Partition[test, {2,3}]` is quite slow in this case because it has to rearrange the elements in the data vector that represents the entries of a packed array in the backend:

```
Flatten[test] == Flatten[Partition[test, {2, 3}]]
```

> False

Using `Span` (`;;`) as follows employs 6 monotonically increasing read operations; in this specific case, these operations are faster than using `Partition`:

```
n = 24000;
test = RandomInteger[1, {n, n}];

a = Total[Partition[test, {2, 3}], {3, 4}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Sum[test[[i ;; ;; 2, j ;; ;; 3]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b
```

> 245.89
>
> 117.943
>
> True

However, this performance advantage seems to decay when the matrix `test` becomes bigger (so swapping is required). E.g., for $n = 4800$, method `b` is about`ten times faster than`a`, but for $n = 24000$, it's only a factor of 4.6 and here it has degraded to a factor of 2 or so...

## SparseArray method

Have I said already that I love `SparseArray`s?

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  c = Dot[
    KroneckerProduct[
     IdentityMatrix[n/2, SparseArray], 
     ConstantArray[1, {1, 2}]
     ],
    Dot[
     test,
     KroneckerProduct[
      IdentityMatrix[n/3, SparseArray], 
      ConstantArray[1, {3, 1}]
      ]
     ]
    ]
  ][[1]]
a == c
```

> 76.3822
>
> True

## The story goes on...

A combination of the `SparseArray` method from above with a `CompiledFunction`):

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}, {k, _Integer}},
   Table[
    Sum[Compile`GetElement[x, i + j], {j, 1, k}],
    {i, 0, Length[x] - 1, k}],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
d = KroneckerProduct[
     IdentityMatrix[n/2, SparseArray], 
     ConstantArray[1, {1, 2}]
     ].cf[test, 3]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == d
```

> 33.5677
>
> True

Comment: Thanks! The sparse array will need some studying on my side for fully understand what's going on there, but it look quite promising in terms of speed up!

Comment: @Fraccalo Have look my latest edits. I seem to have found a method that is twice as fast.

Comment: This looks amazing, thank you so much @Henrik Schumacher! I'll go through the details first thing tomorrow morning, tons of stuff to learn (I'm not very familiar with the compile function, and haven't used sparse arrays more then a couple of times so far, so I really have lot of new things to learn here :) )

Comment: Very nice use of `KroneckerProduct[]`!

Comment: Yeah, thank you @J.M.!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I do have the input data as sparse array now :D do you think your code is easily adaptable to that case?

Comment: @Fraccalo Yeah. In this case, method `c` should be the fastest. Just try it!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I tried to run your code as you wrote it, but if I use the sparse array instead of the matrix (as I did originally) as argument of cf I get an error: CompiledFunction::cfta: Argument SparseArray[Automatic,{12291,12291},0,<<1>>] at position 1 should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size integers. I didn't have time to look closely into your code and how it works, so not sure what the problem is. In the meantime I accept your answer, it was great!

Comment: @Fraccalo Appenrently, you used method `d` which imploys the `CompiledFunction` `cf`. `CompiledFunction` cannot handle `SparseArray`s. Therefore I told you to use method `c` from section "SparseArray method". Anyways, many thanks for the accept!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher oh sorry, it has been such a long day, that I could even distinguish a "c" from a "d" :D you're absolutely right (indeed, I was a bit confused about using compiled functions with sparse array structures) I'll give it another try

Comment: It is actually faster! For a 12k x 12k matrix the compiled version takes 0.082409s, while using sparse arrays takes 0.024485s. I'll keep trying with different matrix sizes!

Answer (score 1):

These two aren't faster, but I found them of interest in that they pose the problem in a different way. The `Downsample` command is easy to describe and use, but slower than then the direct `;;` command as I am building the matrices.

From above, for comparison:

```
n = 6000;
test = RandomInteger[100, {n, n}];

a = Total[Partition[test, {2, 3}], {3, 4}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Sum[test[[i ;; ;; 2, j ;; ;; 3]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b
```

> 1.72742
>
> 0.402294
>
> True

New methods

```
c = Sum[Downsample[test, {2, 3}, {i, j}], {i, 2}, {j, 3}]) //  AbsoluteTiming // First
a == c
```

> 2.12463
>
> True

An experiment with `ListConvolve`. If I could get it to "bound" through the target matrix, it could be pretty fast, as I am throwing out 5/6 of the effort below. I know ListConvolve does take advantage of sparse matrices. Not sure how to exploit that.

```
kernel = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};
d = Downsample[ListCorrelate[kernel, test], {2, 3}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == d
```

> 3.21
>
> True

Comment: To elaborate on the `ListConvolve` method: you could use the `ConvolutionLayer` with a `"Stride"` option instead. Something like `conv=NetReplacePart[NetInitialize[ConvolutionLayer[1,{2,3},"Input"-> {1,n,n},"Stride"-> {2,3}]], {"Weights"->ConstantArray[1,{1,1,2,3}],"Biases"->None}]` and then invoke it with `Round @ First @ conv[{test}, TargetDevice -> "GPU"]`. It's not perfect, but it works.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out to be pokey on my computer. Wish the `ListConvolve` command had a `Stride` option.